# npm won't install dependencies of linked modules

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm using moduleB as a linked dependency in moduleA. moduleB depends on moduleC.

The `package.json` for module B is something like:

```
{
  "name": "moduleB",
  "bin": {
    "moduleB-bin": "index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "moduleC": "^1.0.0",
  }
}
```

The `package.json` for module A is something like:

```
{
  "name": "moduleA",
  "scripts": {
    "run-moduleB": "moduleB-bin"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "moduleB": "file:../moduleB",
  }
}
```

If I then run `npm install moduleB` from moduleA's directory, I end up with a directory structure like:

```
├── moduleA
│   └── node_modules
│       └── moduleB -> ../moduleB
└── moduleB
    └── node_modules
        └── moduleC
```

moduleC is not installed in `moduleA/node_modules`.
This is different from what would happen if moduleB was not a linked dependency.

If I then run `npm run run-moduleB` from moduleA's directory, node complains about not being able to find moduleC.

Is there a way to force npm to install dependencies of linked modules?

(I'm using npm 5.3.0)

Comment: did you ever find a solution?